Как импортировать переменную из класса другого файла?
Есть два файла- main.py и sub.py. Из def __ init __ класса Game в main.py мне надо импортировать переменную в def __ init __ класса Bot в sub.py.
main.py:
from random import randint
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_hp = randint(2, 6)
        self.bot_hp = self.player_hp

sub.py:
import main
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.enemy_hp = main.Game.__init__(self).self.player_hp 
#тут я пытался вставить self.player_hp из main, но не смог, постоянно была ошибка
        self.bot_hp = self.enemy_hp

Как всё-таки приравнять self.enemy_hp к self.player_hp?

может, я и ошибаюсь, но подобные вопросы, вроде бы, задают чуть ли не каждый день.

Создайте объект класса - self.enemy_hp = main.Game().player_hp

Ответ в комментариях от Amgarak:
Создайте объект класса - self.enemy_hp = main.Game().player_hp.
